# aws DynamoDB gives "write EPROTO"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, protocols, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm using dynamoDB to save the data that a web service is generating.
I sometimes (it is not consistent) get the 'EPROTO' error, I read about it and it is a protocol error, but I use aws-sdk (javascript) and I don't state any protocol-related details.

This is how I initialize it:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamoDB = new aws.DynamoDB({
    accessKeyId: config.DynamoDB.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: config.DynamoDB.secretAccessKey,
    region: config.DynamoDB.region
});
```

And I simply use the put api:

```
dynamoDB.putItem(params, function(err, dat) {
    if (err) {
       console.log('ERROR: Putting to dynamo failed with error: ' + err.message);
    }
    else {
       console.log('wipi');
       //passing data 
    }
});
```

`params` is as follow:

```
var params = {
    TableName: config.DynamoDB.tableNames.data, //this is the table name, a string
    Item: {
        id: {
            S: id // this is a generated uid (also a string)
        },
        scheme: {
            S: ivd.version // this is a string of structure 'X.X.X'
        },
        data: {
            S: JSON.stringify(data.data) // data.data is a big object - {arg1: [1, 2, 3...], arg2: '', ...}
        }
    }
};
```

I should mention that it is not even consistent over the same params object (that differs only by the generated uid).

Any ideas what this error means in my case and why would it occur?

Comment: could you provide an example `params`?

Comment: edited my question, but I don't think it helps :(

Comment: how big is your data object? The total item size cannot exceed 400KB.

Comment: @oshnaps: Are you getting this running your code locally, or only in Elastic Beanstalk?  We're seeing similar errors, but only in our deployed code, kinda like https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=689209.

Comment: Actually, I call the api from an ec2, and the node version is 5.2.0, so I'm not sure about the link you gave me... I did try to increase the DB capacity, and in the meanwhile it looks like I don't get it anymore, will continue updating later on.

Comment: @oshnaps any updates? does increasing RCU solves the problem?

Comment: @Werlang Looks like it does, haven't encounter the problem since :)

Comment: @oshnaps hmm...must be a coincidence, because it looks like a node 4.x issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3692

Comment: @Werlang I can't say I'm sure this is the solution, but as I wrote before, it happened on 5.2.0...

Comment: I was getting the same issue when I updated my nod version to 5.4.1. But surprizingly when I changed the node version to 5.2.0. It worked fine.

Comment: Getting it again, node version is 5.2.0, I feel hopeless...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the discussion at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/862:

There seem to be inconsistencies on DynamoDB's side as to which version of TLS DynamoDB uses to communicate in the client.  To get around this, you need to force the SDK to use TLS v1:

```
const https = require('https');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    httpOptions: {
        agent: new https.Agent({
            ciphers: 'ALL',
            secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method'
        })
    }
});

const dynamodbDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    service: dynamodb
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an issue with DynamoDB using node versions > 0.12: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/862

It's believed to be an issue with servers under heavy load not responding with a full TLS response which causes this error to be tossed in newer versions of node.

The only known work-around for now is to downgrade to Node 0.12.